# Fiber-optic connection between two routers is always off, regardless of any configuration

Tags: router, packet-tracer

I have modeled the following network on packettracer. The fiber-optic connections between `Router4` and `Router8` is down and doesn't get up. Whatever I do, the connection remains off. The source file of the model is [uploaded here](https://ufile.io/mmc34). I wonder if anybody knows why the connection is off.

[image]

---

I add running configuration of routers here. Running configuration of Router4:

```
Router#show running-config 
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 1009 bytes
!
version 12.2
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Router
!
!
!
!
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.16.1
!
ip dhcp pool POOL
 network 192.168.16.0 255.255.255.0
 default-router 192.168.16.1
 dns-server 172.16.100.2
!
!
!
ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 192.168.16.1 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface FastEthernet1/0
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface Serial2/0
 no ip address
 clock rate 2000000
 shutdown
!
interface Serial3/0
 no ip address
 clock rate 2000000
 shutdown
!
interface FastEthernet4/0
 ip address 192.168.0.2 255.255.255.0
!
interface FastEthernet5/0
 ip address 10.0.4.1 255.255.255.0
!
router rip
 version 2
 network 10.0.0.0
 network 192.168.0.0
 network 192.168.16.0
 no auto-summary
!
ip classless
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
end
```

Running configuration of Router 8:

```
Router#show running-config 
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 1057 bytes
!
version 12.2
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Router
!
!
!
!
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.137.1
!
ip dhcp pool POOL1
 network 192.168.137.0 255.255.255.0
 default-router 192.168.137.1
 dns-server 172.16.100.2
!
!
!
ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 192.168.137.1 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface FastEthernet1/0
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface Serial2/0
 no ip address
 clock rate 2000000
 shutdown
!
interface Serial3/0
 no ip address
 clock rate 2000000
 shutdown
!
interface FastEthernet4/0
 ip address 10.0.1.2 255.255.255.0
!
interface FastEthernet5/0
 ip address 10.0.2.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface GigabitEthernet8/0
 ip address 10.0.4.2 255.255.255.0
!
router rip
 version 2
 network 10.0.0.0
 network 192.168.137.0
 no auto-summary
!
ip classless
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
end
```

Comment: I don't have packettracer, would it be possible to copy/paste configuration of the two Routers as code in this post? If you do please remember to remove any passwords etc.

Comment: @Cown Thanks I added running-configuration of the two routers

Comment: Try to force your Gi8/0 to 100Mbit full duplex. Commands are `duplex full` and `speed 100`.

Comment: @Cown I run: `Router(config-if)#duplex full`, it says:
`%Command not available for fiber interfaces.`

Comment: @Cown Also when I run `Router(config-if)#speed 100`, it says:
`%Command not available for fiber interfaces.`

Comment: Ok i missed the fiber thing. You are trying to run a Gigabit fiber to a 100 Mbit fiber. That would never work.

Comment: What optic are you using on the Gi8/0 ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61678/discussion-between-cown-and-user4838962).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a mismatch in speed between Router4, Fa5/0 and Router8, Gi8/0. Router8 Gi8/0 was configured with a Gbit GBIC module, which was connected to a 100 Mbit FX GBIC module. The mismatch caused the connectivity problems.